# Scheduled event to update one column according to other

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a scheduled event for my mysql database in which I want to update one column according to other column.If the current time is greater than equal to the the time in time column ,state should be updated 1.That's what I have tried so far.Also I will have more than 1000 rows rows to be checked ,will that scheduler be efficient

table eventtable

```
 State             time
    1          2019-05-09 11:23:00
    0          2019-05-07 14:40:00
    0          2019-05-08 09:23:00 
    0          2019-05-09 12:23:00 




    CREATE EVENT updateblock
        ON SCHEDULE
          EVERY 1 MINUTE
            DO
    update eventtable 
    set state=1 
    where time >= now()
```